# When will ANACRONTAB run cron.daily?

Tags: cron, cron.daily

My RHEL has the following anacrontab config file, it has START_HOURS_RANGE and RANDOM_DELAY both missing, what hour does cron.daily start everyday? My guess is it is random. Is it true?

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

1       65      cron.daily              run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       70      cron.weekly             run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
30      75      cron.monthly            run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. More details are in the documentation.